# How to change the color of ellipse at mouse over of button WPF (c# ,wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added an ellipse on a button.
but as of now on mouse over of that button I need to change the background.
so colould not able to do with normal trigger i.e with setting background property on mouse over event.

```
    <Style x:Key="RButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>                          
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Elipse1" Fill="Red" ></Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Center"                VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value = "Orange"/>
                </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: we cannot change the element of button on its over ..so any help

Comment: have you even done a google search for this .
TargetName="Elipse1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TemplateBinding` inside template to bind `Button.Background` property and set default value as another `Setter` of your `Style`

```xml
<Style x:Key="RButton" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>                          
               <Ellipse x:Name="Elipse1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

or, if you don't want to use `Button.Background` property, you can target `Ellipse` by name

```xml
<Setter TargetName="Elipse1" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Style`:

```
 <Style x:Key="RButton" TargetType="Button">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Grid>
                     <Ellipse x:Name="Elipse1" Fill="Red" ></Ellipse>
                     <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                 </Grid>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="Fill" Value = "Orange" TargetName="Elipse1" ></Setter>
                     </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```